# Declarate function type in OCaml (like in Haskell)

Tags: haskell, ocaml

Is it possible to function in OCaml with given type?
For example in Haskell I can create something like that:

```
f :: [a] -> Int
f [] = 0
f (x:xs) = 1 + f xs
```

Comment: I've edited question. Maybe now it's more clear.

Comment: @JohnMalick: I think the other question+answer provides what you're looking for.

Comment: use type coercition of Ocaml (refer also to the already answered question).

Comment: @PierreG.: Did you revenge downvote this question?

Answer (score 0):

why do you want to do so ? Ocaml infers type, so you do not need to declare the type of your function (except when you want to export your function).
In your example :

```
let rec f a = match a with 
[] -> 0
| x::xs -> 1 + f xs
```

Ocaml will deduce that f is expecting a list, and will result an Int.

Comment: In Haskell I also don't need to write types. Is not an answer to my question.

Comment: @JohnMalick If you want to define the function type your question is a duplicate. If you just want a working polymorphic define then this is the answer.

Comment: I wanted to define own type. Because of that my question is duplicate.